# How do I create a Firebase Dynamic Link with a wildcard in the path?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, branch.io

I am trying to create a Firebase Dynamic Link that has a wildcard in the path, like this: `https://my-site.pages.link/daily-post/*` where `*` is a wildcard that can be any string. In my case it would be a date like: `https://my-site.pages.link/daily-post/2023-01-01`.

Does the ability to have wildcards exist or do I have to create each link individually?

If not does branch.io have this ability?

Alternatively would a redirect from `https://links.my-site.com/daily-post/2023-01-01` to a manually built Firebase Dynamic Link work or does this causes any issues with google analytics / google ads communication?

I've tried searching but have not found a clear answer to this question.